# How to restore a Tensorflow Model trained using Dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore, tensorflow-datasets

I'm training my model using the Dataset API with a feedable iterator, like in the Importing Data Tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets).
The problem is, when restoring the model. It wil also restore the handle placeholder with its shape from training. That means it is expecting to get an example and a label to it.

```
    def loadTFRecord(filenames):          
      dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([filenames])
      dataset = dataset.map(extract_img_func)
      dataset = dataset.batch(batchsize)
      handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
      iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
      training_iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
      next_element = iterator.get_next() 
      training_handle = self.sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
      return next_element #next_element[0] is the example img, next_element[1] is the label

    def model_fn(images, labels=None, train=False):
      input_layer = images
      ...
      predictions = last_layer
      if train:
        return predictions

      # Calculate loss
      loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
      learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=learningRate, staircase=True)
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
      train_op = optimizer.minimize(
          loss=loss,
          global_step=global_step)

      return train_op, predictions, loss
```

With this i am creating my model for training:

```
examples, labels = loadTFRecord("path/to/tfrecord")
model_fn(examples, labels=labels)
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=0.5)
... #training here
saver.save(sess, "path/to/")
```

Now the problem is, when i want to restore the model for inference.
What i want to do is restore the model and pass in another feedable iterator which loads some .png files from disk. I am doing this similar to loading the TFRecord file.

```
def load_images(filenames):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.image.resize_images(self.normalize(tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(x), channels = 3)), [IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT]))
  dataset = dataset.batch(1)
  iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  next_img = iterator.get_next()
  training_handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
  return next_img
```

Now the problem is when passing it to the restored model like this:

```
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelbasepath + ".meta")
  saver.restore(sess, modelbasepath)
  ... # restore operations here
  # finally run predictions, error occurs here!
  predictions = sess.run([predictions], feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Number of components does not match: expected 2 types but got 1.
 [[Node: IteratorFromStringHandle_2 = IteratorFromStringHandle[output_shapes=[[?,80,80,3], [?,80,80,?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_0)]]
```

Which tells me that is is expecting to also get a label, while i am only feeding an image to predict.

How can i overcome this? Is there a way to change the shape of the placeholder or how would one implement this so it is possible to restore a model trained with the datatset API and feedable dicts?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. However, I could not come up with a clean solution. I ended up creating a dummy tensor for the label that I return when loading images. There may be a better way of doing this but this solution should now allow you to run the model.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(load_images)

def load_images(x):
    image = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(x), channels = 3))
    image = self.normalize(image)
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT])

    # Assuming label is one channel, can slice image to get correct dims
    label = tf.zeros_like(image[:, :, 0:1]) 

    return image, label
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is a good workaround. However i would like to know how this is done the right way!